# Why to add transitional dependencies to Berksfile?

Tags: chef-infra, berksfile

I'm developing a cookbook (`my_cookbook`) that has dependencies with another cookbook (`another_cookbook`) that has dependencies with another cookbook (`another_cookbook2`).
Why do I need to specify transitional dependencies in `my_cookbook` Berksfile (means to add the `another_cookbook2` dependency to Berskfile)? If the dependency with `another_cookbook2` was already specified in the `another_cookbook` Berksfile?

```
$ berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
...
Unable to satisfy constraints on package another_cookbook2, which does not exist, due to solution constraint (another_cookbook = 0.0.1). Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on another_cookbook2: [(another_cookbook = 0.0.1) -> (another_cookbook2 >= 0.0.0)]
Missing artifacts: another_cookbook2
...
```

I'm trying to do this before uploading my cookbook to a Chef server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.
If you share your `Berskfile`s, we can show you what's up.
Dependencies are listed in the `metadata.rb` file, not the `Berksfile`.  The `Berksfile` just tells Berks where to find those dependencies.

If you don't have a decent Berks API endpoint in your berksfile, like supermarket.chef.io, then you may have to list location for the dependent cookbooks.

Unlike `metadata.rb`, berksfiles are not built recursively, and thus the `Berksfile` in a dependent cookbook will not be used.